# executing pig script file with multiple stores in embedded pig program

Tags: apache-pig

I want to execute a pig script file in embedded pig program which is shown below

----testPig.pig-----

```
A = load '/user/biadmin/student' using PigStorage() as (name:chararray);
B = foreach A generate name; 
store B into '/user/biadmin/myoutput001';
```

for this I have written code as shown below

```
> PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE);
> pigServer.registerScript("testPig.pig");
```

but it is not working.I have checked this in grunt-shell mode. there it is working fine.
So I made changes like this

---testPig.pig -----

```
A = load '/user/biadmin/student' using PigStorage() as (name:chararray);
B = foreach A generate name;
--store B into '/user/biadmin/myoutput001';
```

Embedded pig code for this is

```
> PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE,prt);
> pigServer.registerScript(path);
> pigServer.store("B","/user/biadmin/myoutput20");
```

Now the modified code is working fine. 
So now my doubt is

1. **why I was not able to execute pig script which is having store command?**
2. **How can I execute pig script file which is having store command?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `PigServer` code is not working because; when you call `.registerScript()`, by default, `PigServer` sets the interactive mode flag on `GruntParser` to `false`. From the `PigServer` source code:

```
public void registerScript(InputStream in, Map<String,String> params,List<String> paramsFiles) throws IOException {
    try {
        String substituted = doParamSubstitution(in, params, paramsFiles);
        GruntParser grunt = new GruntParser(new StringReader(substituted));
    /********************************************/
        grunt.setInteractive(false);
    /********************************************/
        grunt.setParams(this);
        grunt.parseStopOnError(true);
    } catch (org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.ParseException e) {
        log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        throw new IOException(e.getCause());
    }
}
```

Quoting from the `GruntParser` source code:

> In interactive mode, executes the plan right away whenever a STORE command is encountered.

This means that **when interactive mode is not active**, `STORE`commands will be ignored (that is they won't run automatically) until further `PigServer.openIterator` or `PigServer.store` calls (that is you explicitly make a call requiring the `STORE` line).

As for your second question, you might want to have a look at [PigRunner](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/PigRunner.html) class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... now I got the reason, But how to solve that issue?? I didn't find PigRunner.class in my pig.jar file.

Comment: Well, it is there; otherwise it wouldn't have [Java docs](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/PigRunner.html)  and it wouldn't be in [pig's svn](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pig/tags/release-0.9.1/src/org/apache/pig/PigRunner.java?view=markup), right? :)

Comment: Mine one is old version.. I found that class in the new Version of PIg [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpigjar.htm)..**Thank you all**

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out; remember to accept the proper answer(s) for your question(s) on StackOverflow.

Comment: ya I know that.. But let me check with PigRunner class 1st. If it works then only i can accept rt?